# What does "wield knife" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, headlinese

What does "wield knife" mean? That must be some idiom, but dictionaries are silent on this. I mean, they obviously resigned, but there must be more to it

[image]

Comment: It's "headlinese", dispensing with the definite article from the well-established usage ***to wield THE knife*** - to be the one (usually of multiple attackers) who *visibly* delivers the decisive / fatal wound to a victim.

Comment: There's no idiom here. Sunak and Javid are holding or using a metaphorical weapon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "knife" is here being used metaphorically, and stands for a weapon in general. They are wielding a knife, or, metaphorically, attacking. The metaphor suggests that they have some power to harm Johnson (this power is, metaphorically, the knife), and they are somehow using, threatening to use, or taking actions suggesting they will use it, with this use metaphorically being "wielding" the knife. This brings to mind the metaphor of "knife in his back", which refers to waiting until someone is unprepared and/or in a moment of weakness (metaphorically, they have their back turned to you) to move against them, betraying some previous trust.

Comment: And the lack of article is just 'headlinese'.

Answer (score 1):

To "wield a knife" literally means to hold a knife in such a way as to use it as a weapon. In the context of this tabloid, Sunak and Javid are figuratively wielding a knife in the sense that they are inflicting great political harm to Boris Johnson by resigning. The knife in this case is their resignation.